# use the queue to manage the mutiple of notifications

Tags: ios, queue, frequency

target: 
Now, I have a mission that is use the queue to manage the mutiple of notifications. So no matter how many notifications app received in a short time when app is active, app can play the notification UI(firstly show the notification UI, then dismiss it) at a fixed frequency. For example, play the notification UI every 2 seconds. But I have no idea about how to control the frequency of the task in the queue,Thank you!

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you are talking about. "The queue"? What queue? Are you talking about creating a serial queue? "The multiple of notifications"? What notifications? Remote notifications? Local notifications?

Comment: Sorry about that, I want to use the serial queue to do it, for me, I just want to get the UI result whether it is local or remote notification.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a rather complex task, and would involve learning about several technologies.

I'm not sure if queues are appropriate. A simple array and a timer might be better.

Set up an array in your app delegate to hold notifications that need to be displayed. When you receive a notification, add it to your array.

Then set up a timer that runs when the app is active. When the timer fires, pull a notification off the front of the array and display it.

Explaining how to do each of those things is beyond the scope of a SO post. You need to do some research on your own, write some code, and post *specific* questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you, I will remember the teachings. In fact, I already learn some knowledge and write some code before the post. Since this is my first use of queue, I don't have much confidence and I don't  get the result I wanted, so I want to get some other thinking.The next time I will post specific questions if I get stuck.

Comment: Again, I don't think queues are a good fit for the problem you need to solve. A simple array and a timer would likely be better.